# ESC/POS "Select bit-image mode" vs "Print raster bit image"

Tags: escpos

I'm working on some code to print an image from an Android device to a Bixolon SPP-R200. From what I can tell, it emulates ESC POS. I noticed that there are two commands for printing images. "Select bit-image mode" (`ESC *`) or "Print raster bit image" (`GS v 0`).

What's the difference between these two commands? Why would I choose one command over the other?

Comment: [This](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=72) says that `GS v 0` is an "obsolete command".

Comment: Possibly helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26269019/print-bitmap-full-page-width-in-thermal-dot-printer-using-esc-pos-in-java

Comment: @JimmyB which command do you suggest we should be using now as a replacement?:

Comment: ["It is recommended to use graphics function (GS ( L <Function 50> and GS ( L / GS 8 L <Function 112> ). The graphics function is superior in operating to GS v 0 for the following reasons: ..."](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=94) :)

Comment: Obsolete as it may be (for Epson), it would be much more interesting to know which of these `ESC *`, `GS v 0`, `GS (  L...` and why not `GS ( k` are supported by which printers - i.e. which is the _most common_ in the wild regardless of "standard" obsolescence. A pretty table would be nice.