# ESC/POS Protocol print bitmap

Tags: escpos

I need to print an graphical image using ESCPOS protocol.
So far I have researched following commands available on my printer:

> GS v 0 m xL xH yL yH d1 … dk
>
> ESC * m nL nH d1…dk

Let's say I got following image where *0* and *1* represents a single pixel:

```
   |||||
-- 00000
-- 01010
-- 01010
---00000
```

1. <strike>Which command I should use for this purpose?</strike>
2. It is total unclear for me from documentations how to use these commands to print image and how printer reads my image and how I should pass that data. Command to print top first few lines of the image above with explanations of all parameters would be very helpful.

---

EDIT:

Regarding 1. - [ESC/POS "Select bit-image mode" vs "Print raster bit image"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41039088/esc-pos-select-bit-image-mode-vs-print-raster-bit-image)

Comment: did you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I was in your same situation, the documentation it's not clear. Finally I went to GitHub and found a [library in Java](https://github.com/anastaciocintra/escpos-coffee) that makes most of things with ESC/POS commands.

It worked for me. If you are not working with Java you can still look through the code and try to understand.