# Intermect PB42 print image

Tags: intermec

i am trying to print receipt from  windows mobile 5 to intermec PB42 (thermal printer) , i had tried the ESC/P commands also easy print commands .

i tried also ESC/POS from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26269019/print-bitmap-full-page-width-in-thermal-dot-printer-using-esc-pos-in-java) but still cannot print .

and i found PRN file that contains image and it worked but i cannot generate this format and i do not know what is this format (file link https://www.dropbox.com/s/0wonnt68nltxd4j/PrintPad_Receipt_Demo.prn?dl=0).

Answer (score 0):

Intermec PB series printers used the Intermec Printing Language, IPL.  See http://apps.intermec.com/downloads/eps_man/934-013.pdf for details.

Comment: thanks @marc-balmer but i had tried all commands in this file in string format and ascii and all of them are not working but i had found some other document using "easy print" command and some of them only worked and finally ended up printing image