# How to define NV bit image in thermal printer ESC/POS

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, escpos

I have been looking for some sample for quite a long time now but did not find any. I want to feed the image to printer in its memory (or cache) and then print it out. I have the documentation of the command:

```
FS q n [xL xH yL yH d1...dk]1...[xL xH yL yH d1...dk]n
[Name] Define NV bit image
[Format]  ASCII   FS q   n [xL xH yL yH d1...dk]1...[ xL xH yL yH d1...dk]n
          Hex     1C 71  n [xL xH yL yH d1...dk]1...[ xL xH yL yH d1...dk]n
          Decimal 28 113 n [xL xH yL yH d1...dk]1...[ xL xH yL yH d1...dk]n
```

I just couldn't get my head around this part:

```
[xL xH yL yH d1...dk]1...[ xL xH yL yH d1...dk]n
```

No sample available on internet as to how to use this parameter.

Comment: Similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26269019/print-bitmap-full-page-width-in-thermal-dot-printer-using-esc-pos-in-java

Comment: @huse.ckr its not quite the same and i have seen it before. they are talking about printing image and not defining it into the printer.

Comment: I got it you are right.

Comment: The image format is explained in detail in the ESC/POS programming guide by EPSON.

Answer (score 0):

```
[xL xH yL yH d1...dk]1...[ xL xH yL yH d1...dk]n
```

defines the Image you want to send, you can send multiple images hence (n) in the end.
If you only want to send one picture you only need to define one Array.

xL and xH = width of the image in pixels for example xL=64 xH=0

yL and yH = heigth of the image in pixels for example yL =96 xH=0

to be honest I don't know why one can set a Height for each of those coordinates..

d1 ... dk = the image data in bytes

[image: how to set the image data]